# VBA to calculate when production will finish

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying build a macro to give me the date and time production will end based on a value entered into cell A2. At present each unit takes 1 min 5 sec to produce. the shift will finish at 00:30 and restart at 05:30 so I would like it to take this into consideration.

Some examples

If the date/time is 14/03/2017 22:00 and I enter 55 into cell A2 I would expect a return of 14/03/2017 23:00 in cell E2.
If the date/time is 14/03/2017 22:00 and I entered 1 into cell A2 I would expect a return of 14/03/2017 22:01 in cell E2.
If the time is 14/03/2017 23:55 and I entered 55 into cell A2 I would expect a return of 15/03/2017 05:55

So at the moment I am using this code which works well within the shift but I cant get any further with it ie. going into the next days production. 
Range("A2").Value * Range("C2").Value + Now()

A2 being the number of units and C2 being the process time 0,1,5

Many thanks for your help /advice

Comment: Why don't you show the code that you have written and ask a question about the code? All you have done is informed us that you have a desire to write a program. That isn't the same thing as actually asking a question. See [ask].

Comment: This is grade school addition and multiplication. The only possible complication would be the addition of CEILING instead of trusting the innate rounding qualities of date/time cell formatting.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have edited post . How ever I think maybe I am going about it the wrong way. Very new to VBA

Comment: Why are you using `0,1,5` for the time-per-unit instead of `00:01:05`? Is this a regional time format? Is that a real number? Real numbers/dates/times are right-aligned by default unless you change the cell alignment. Text is left-aligned.

Comment: sorry yes it does show 0:01:05 . I used =time(0,1,5)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is. The maths are (units * time-per-unit) + start time. The brackets are for visual clrity only; mathematical precedence will ensure that the multiplication takes place before the addition.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    .Range("E2") = Now
    .Range("F2") = .Range("E2").Value2 + (.Range("A2").Value2 * .Range("C2").Value2)
    .Range("G2") = Application.Ceiling(.Range("F2").Value2, TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
    .Range("E2:G2").NumberFormat = "[Color10][$-en-US]dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm;[Color3]@"
End With
```

FWIW, I've had better success using `.Value2` instead of `.Value` as it is a raw numerical without additional date/time/currency information.

Answer (score 0):

This took a little time but it turned out rather nice. Follow these instructions to test.
Create a standard code module in the workbook in which you want the action to occur. The name will be "Module1" by default. I suggest you change it to "Main" or some better, descriptive name. Paste the following enumerations at the top of your module, including the option statement.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                ' Worksheet navigation
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2
    NwsQty = 1          ' Columns (not necessarily contiguous):
    NwsTime             ' time to produce one unit
    NwsStart            ' date/time
    NwsEnd              ' date/time
End Enum
```

This enumeration serves to identify rows and columns in your worksheet. Note that columns are numbered (1=A, 2=B, 3=C etc.) Enumerations without a value assume the value of the previous one +1. So, NwsEnd = 4 = column D. You can set up the sheet according to the enum or adjust the enum values to match your sheet, but you must have a column for each of Quantity, Production time, Production Start time, and Production completion time. NwsFirstDataRow serves to prevent the macro from changing data you don't want changed - at least those in the caption row, here presumed to be row 1.
Now past the next enumeration below the above.

```
Enum Nsh                ' Shift  (use 24h format)
    NshStart = 530      ' read as 05:30 (on current day)
    NshEnd = 2430       ' read as 00:30 (on next day)
End Enum
```

This enum holds a code for your shift time. In the future, if your working hours change, you can modify the code's output simply by changing these numbers.
The next sub is doing most of the work.

```
Sub SetCompletion(Ws As Worksheet, R As Long)
    ' 20 Mar 2017

    Dim Qty As Long
    Dim ShiftQty As Long, DayQty As Long
    Dim UnitTime As Double, StartTime As Double
    Dim ComplDate As Double
    Dim Days As Integer

    With Rows(R)
        Qty = .Cells(NwsQty).Value
        UnitTime = .Cells(NwsTime).Value
        StartTime = .Cells(NwsStart).Value
        If Qty And (UnitTime > 0) And (StartTime > 0) Then
            ComplDate = (UnitTime * Qty) + StartTime
            ShiftQty = QtyTillShiftEnd(StartTime, UnitTime)

            If ShiftQty < Qty Then
                Qty = Qty - ShiftQty
                DayQty = DailyProduction(UnitTime)
                ComplDate = StartTime + 1 + Int(Qty / DayQty)
                ComplDate = ComplDate + UnitTime * (Qty Mod DayQty)
            End If

            .Cells(NwsEnd).Value = ComplDate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Its basic calculation method is to first calculate how many units can be produced from the start of production until the end of that day's shift. Then calculate the full days' production, and calculate the completion from the number of remaining units to be produced on the last day. No such calculation will be made while any of the 3 required components are missing (Qty, Time, StartTime). The following functions are helping in the calculation. Paste them at the bottom of the same "Main" code module.

```
Private Function QtyTillShiftEnd(ByVal StartTime As Double, _
                                  ByVal UnitTime As Double) As Double
    ' 20 Mar 2017

    Dim ProdTime As Double

    ProdTime = (Int(StartTime) + NshToDays(NshEnd) - StartTime)
    QtyTillShiftEnd = (ProdTime + 0.0001) / UnitTime
End Function
```

Calculates the quantity that can be produced from the start time until the end of the first production day's shift. The next function calculates a full day's production.

```
Private Function DailyProduction(UnitTime As Double) As Integer
    ' 19 Mar 2017
    DailyProduction = Int((NshToDays(NshEnd) - NshToDays(NshStart) + 0.000001) / UnitTime)
End Function
```

When working with Double type numbers, required for time calculations, VB has difficulty calculating zero. The 0.000001 added to the result ensures that the calculation doesn't end up below zero when zero is required. The next function converts the encoded shift times from `Enum` Nsh into fractions of days which this program can work with.

```
Private Function NshToDays(TimeCode As Nsh) As Double
    ' 19 Mar 2017

    Dim H As Double, M As Double

    H = Int(TimeCode / 100)
    M = TimeCode Mod 100
    NshToDays = (1 / 24 * H) + (1 / 24 / 60 * M)
End Function
```

The next function corrects wrong entries in the StartTime column `NwsStart`.

```
Function AdjustedStartTime(ByVal StartTime As Double) As Double
    ' 19 Mar 2017
    ' return new StartTime or 0

    Dim Fun As Double
    Dim StartDate As Long
    Dim ShiftStart As Double, ShiftEnd As Double

    ShiftStart = NshToDays(NshStart)
    ShiftEnd = NshToDays(NshEnd)
    StartDate = Int(StartTime)
    StartTime = StartTime - StartDate
    Fun = StartTime

    If ShiftEnd > 1 Then
        If StartTime < (ShiftStart - Int(ShiftStart)) Then
            If StartTime > (ShiftEnd - Int(ShiftEnd)) Then Fun = ShiftStart
        End If
    Else
        If (StartTime - Int(StartTime)) < ShiftStart Then
            Fun = ShiftStart
        Else
            If StartTime > ShiftEnd Then Fun = ShiftStart + 1
        End If
    End If
    AdjustedStartTime = Fun + StartDate
End Function
```

This function's action is to make sure that no one enters a time like 4:00 am. If someone does the entry will be changed to 05:30 because that's when the shift starts.
The last procedure in this code sheet formats cells.

```
Sub FormatCells(Row As Range)
    ' 19 Mar 2017

    Dim Fmt As Variant, Clm As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' match for number formats in 'Fmt' to the column numbers in 'Clm'
    Clm = Array(NwsQty, NwsTime, NwsStart, NwsEnd)
    Fmt = Array("#,##0", "hh:mm:ss", "dd mmm hh:mm", "dd mmm hh:mm")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Clm)
        Row.Cells(Clm(i)).NumberFormat = Fmt(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This sub will be called whenever a production quantity is entered. You can adjust the cell formats here. This goes especially for the date formats which I may not have done to your liking.

Now, still in the VBE window, please find the code sheet for the worksheet on which you have the columns first above enumerated. It might be listed in the Project window as `Sheet1(Sheet1)` or similar. It is important that you identify the correct sheet and paste the following procedure there.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 20 Mar 2017

    Dim Entry As Variant

    With Target
        ' no action when more than one cell is modified at once
        If .Cells.Count = 1 And .Row >= NwsFirstDataRow Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Entry = .Value
            Select Case .Column
                Case NwsQty
                    If Val(Entry) < 1 Then
                        If Len(Entry) > 0 Then
                            MsgBox "Please enter a number representing" & vbCr & _
                                   "the quantity to be produced.", vbExclamation, _
                                   "Invalid entry"
                            .Select
                        End If
                    Else
                        FormatCells Rows(.Row)
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    End If
                Case NwsTime
                    If Val(Entry) Then
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    Else
                        If Len(Entry) > 0 Then
                            MsgBox "The production time must be entered" & vbCr & _
                                   "in the format h:m:s", vbExclamation, _
                                   "Invalid entry"
                            .Select
                        End If
                    End If
                Case NwsStart
                    If Val(Entry) Then
                        If (Val(Entry) < 1) Then .Value = Entry + Date
                        Entry = AdjustedStartTime(.Value)
                        If .Value <> Entry Then
                            MsgBox "On " & Format(Entry, "mmm d") & " production doesn't " & _
                                   "start until " & Format(Entry, "h:mm") & "." & vbCr & _
                                   "Your entry was adjusted accordingly.", _
                                   vbInformation, "Corrected time entry"
                            .Value = Entry
                        End If
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    Else
                        MsgBox "The production start must be entered as a Time" & vbCr & _
                               "or Dtae/Time value in the format [d/m/yy] HH:mm", _
                               vbExclamation, "Invalid entry"
                        .Select
                    End If
                Case NwsEnd
                    MsgBox "Recalculate with a new production start?" & vbCr & _
                           "The completion date is the result of a calculation." & vbCr & _
                           "To change it, modify the unit production time.", _
                            vbInformation, "Invalid action"
                    Application.Undo
            End Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You can get a fair idea of what this procedure does by reading the various error messages it can spit out. You can modify these texts. Note that you can enter the start time as a time or Date/Time. If you enter time only the macro will add the current date automatically. In the absence of errors this macro will call the sub `SetCompletion` which will write the completion date to the sheet if all criteria for its calculation are present.
Note that there is no protection of your data after change of Enum Nsh. To avoid overwriting existing completion dates which were calculated with previously correct shift times, set the enumeration `NwsFirstDataRow` to exclude rows you wish to protect in this way.

All components have been tested, but the project as a whole is rather complex and you would do well to watch the results in real life. You may have noticed that I have structured the code in such a way that faults can easily be attributed to specific functions which may then have to be improved without putting everything into question.

Comment: WOW... just.... WOW....Thankyou so much for your time and effort... I feel as though I am letting you down as I cant get it to work. I have pasted into module changed name to main then last bit pasted into Sheet1(Sheet1) but nothing is happening when changing the qty. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong so frustrating

Comment: Nothing should happen until Qty, prod time and start time have been entered. If you had a code crash for some reason the application events might be left disabled. Enter Application.EnableEvents = True n the Immediate window and press Return. Check in the Immediate window with ? Application.EnableEvents and Expect True as an answer. If neither of these do let me know and I shall scratch my head.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding..Which immediate window are we talking about the module or the sheet1(sheet1) or even somewhere else

Comment: It's in the VBE window, at the bottom. If not there, enable it from the View menu. You can also enable Events by restarting Excel.

Comment: Another thought. The event procedure won't run if it isn't in the correct location. It must bei n the code sheet of the worksheet n which you enter the Qty. Also, the column in which you have Qty and the two time values must be declared correctly in the Enum.

Comment: Hi ..ok found it ... yes returns True ... would it be something I have done wrong then ?

Comment: ok, so the qty and 2 time values are all in sheet1. the main code I pasted into sheet1(sheet1) the qty is in cell A1,the process time is in cell B1 the 2 times are in cells C1 & D1 so in the Enum I have declared them as 3 & 4 is that not correct?

Comment: Not quite. Only the event procedure should be in the Sheet1(Sheet1) code module. All the other code should be in a normal code module. (Right-click -> Insert -> Module = by default "Module1". I gave you NwsFirstDataRow = 2. Unless you changed it, the event will not fire when you enter anything in the first row. I gave you NwsQty=1, NwsTime=2, NwsStart=3 and NwsEnd=4, meaning A, B, C, and D. (2, 3, and 4 are declared by default, each 1 more than the previous.) You can declare them explicitly without ill effect. With this setting, a result should appear in column D after A, B and C have been set

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your patience and sorry for my limited understanding. I've repeated all the steps again as follows. Opened the VBA editor "alt F11", right clicked inserted a module, pasted all the code in here but not the last piece "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)". for the last piece of code I double clicked on sheet1(sheet1) and pasted it in here......In the actual workbook sheet1 in cell's A1 I have the qty(55), B1 the process time (00:01:05, C1 the start time (05:30), D1 the finish time (00:30). Have I done this correct? where should I get the return value?

Comment: Change should occur in the finish time when you change any of the parameters used in its calculation. In my testing, i worked with a production time of 15 minutes (4 per hour) which makes it easy to check the end time offered by the macro. Note that start and end are Date/Time values. I presume you don't mention the date because it's irrelevant for your example. To answer your question precisely: the "return value" is always n the end time you see in your worksheet.

Comment: Hi. nothing happening still, are the steps I put above correct? How or what format are you entering the process time ?

Comment: Sorry about that :-( Yes, I suspect the formats, too. Enter 0:15:0 as production time. Try 5:30 in the start time column and see, if the macro writes 24/3/17 05:30 in that cell when you press enter. Type ? Now() in the Immediate window and tell me the output you see on Enter. Add this line of code in the event procedure, just below the existing line "Target", MsgBox .Address & vbCr & NwsQty & vbCr & NwsTime & vbCr & NwsStart & vbCr & NwsEnd. This will show a messagte box when you change something in the sheet. Tell me if and what it shows.

Comment: Hi there. so this is really strange, all on it's own with out any changes it started working perfectly earlier, I changed start time to =now() and still working a treat, really pleased with it. Then I had to pop out so saved and shut down. Now I've re-opened to do some testing etc and it's not working I haven't changed anything from earlier, so strange.I had already had it formatted as you've said above. Now doing what you said  ?now() in immediate window returned 3/24/2017 and adding that code, well nothing happened I guess where it's not working now. Any ideas what would cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the date format, more specifically, the input date format in the start time column. The macro will only calculate if a start time is given. So, when the start time is given but not recognised as such no calculation takes place.

I programmed for day/month/year and you are using the American system. Please replace the existing procedure of the same name with this one.

```
Sub FormatCells(Row As Range)
    ' 25 Mar 2017

    Dim Fmt As Variant, Clm As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' match for number formats in 'Fmt' to the column numbers in 'Clm'
    Clm = Array(NwsQty, NwsTime, NwsStart, NwsEnd)
    Fmt = Array("#,##0", "hh:mm:ss", "mmm dd hh:mm", "mmm dd hh:mm")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Clm)
        Row.Cells(Clm(i)).NumberFormat = Fmt(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Modifications have also been made to the event procedure which will now recognise dates entered in your format. Please remember that you are supposed to be able to enter the start time as 7:30 and have the cell display Mar 25 07:30. Try this. also try entering "Mar 20 7:30", "3/20/17 7:30", "3/20 7:30", and then "3/20/17 14:00" and perhaps "3/20/17 2:00 PM". If it doesn't work that would be indication of bigger wrongs behind the scenes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 25 Mar 2017

    Dim Entry As Variant

    With Target
        ' no action when more than one cell is modified at once
        If .Cells.Count = 1 And .Row >= NwsFirstDataRow Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Entry = .Value
            Select Case .Column
                Case NwsQty
                    If Val(Entry) < 1 Then
                        If Len(Entry) > 0 Then
                            MsgBox "Please enter a number representing" & vbCr & _
                                   "the quantity to be produced.", vbExclamation, _
                                   "Invalid entry"
                            .Select
                        End If
                    Else
                        FormatCells Rows(.Row)
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    End If
                Case NwsTime
                    If Val(Entry) Then
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    Else
                        If Len(Entry) > 0 Then
                            MsgBox "The production time must be entered" & vbCr & _
                                   "in the format h:m:s", vbExclamation, _
                                   "Invalid entry"
                            .Select
                        End If
                    End If
                Case NwsStart
                    If IsDate(Entry) Then
                        If (CDbl(Entry) < 1) Then .Value = Entry + Date
                        Entry = AdjustedStartTime(.Value)
                        If .Value <> Entry Then
                            MsgBox "On " & Format(Entry, "mmm d") & " production doesn't " & _
                                   "start until " & Format(Entry, "h:mm") & "." & vbCr & _
                                   "Your entry was adjusted accordingly.", _
                                   vbInformation, "Corrected time entry"
                            .Value = Entry
                        End If
                        SetCompletion ActiveSheet, .Row
                    Else
                        MsgBox "The production start must be entered as a Time" & vbCr & _
                               "or Date/Time value in the format [m/d/yy] HH:mm", _
                               vbExclamation, "Invalid entry"
                        .Select
                    End If
                Case NwsEnd
                    MsgBox "Recalculate with a new production start?" & vbCr & _
                           "The completion date is the result of a calculation." & vbCr & _
                           "To change it, modify the unit production time.", _
                            vbInformation, "Invalid action"
                    Application.Undo
            End Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Last but not least, I discovered an error in the calculation of the completion time affecting production time ending not on the same day. I corrected it. Please exchange the functions.

```
Sub SetCompletion(ws As Worksheet, R As Long)
    ' 25 Mar 2017

    Dim Qty As Long
    Dim ShiftQty As Long, DayQty As Long
    Dim UnitTime As Double, StartTime As Double
    Dim ComplDate As Double
    Dim Days As Integer

    With Rows(R)
        Qty = .Cells(NwsQty).Value
        UnitTime = .Cells(NwsTime).Value
        StartTime = .Cells(NwsStart).Value
        If Qty And (UnitTime > 0) And (StartTime > 0) Then
            ComplDate = (UnitTime * Qty) + StartTime
            ShiftQty = QtyTillShiftEnd(StartTime, UnitTime)

            If ShiftQty < Qty Then
                Qty = Qty - ShiftQty
                DayQty = DailyProduction(UnitTime)
                ComplDate = Int(StartTime) + 1 + NshToDays(NshStart) + Int(Qty / DayQty)
                ComplDate = ComplDate + UnitTime * (Qty Mod DayQty)
            End If

            .Cells(NwsEnd).Value = ComplDate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Actually, this procedure should be further amended to recognise weekends, but I hope that your production wouldn't stop on Sundays :-)

I shall appreciate your bearing with me in case you still face a problem with the dates. I could change the default settings on my PC for better testing, but so far I have avoided doing so. :-)

Comment: Hi again. This is weird, I tried it again on 2 different occasions today and working fine, any way I have changed the code to your updated version now. Strange its an American version as I am in the UK. My work version will def be UK so I'll change the date format back for that when finished testing. At the moment it is calculating correctly within the same day but once it goes past the finish time (00:30) it miss calculates, seems to be adding on 24 hrs + the process time(I think). eg (input 25 march at 20:23) 00:31 should return as 26 march 05:31 but returns as 26 march 20:24. Thanks again

Comment: Also I will mostly use the start time as =now() although being able to choose the start time will be a great asset in some situations :-)

Comment: This thread is getting out of hand. Let's split it up. You have two issues. One is the correct calculation which is done in the sub SetCompletion. A day is added there (ComplDate = Int(StartTime) + 1 + ...) and you might look into the logic of that yourself. That is precisely the line I corrected yesterday and I might have been hasty. The other is the date entry. Could you raise a new question about that? Like "How to add date automatically when time is entered".

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your calculation error. Please cite an exact example with quantity, production time, start time and the correct end time as well as the wrong end time the macro generates. BTW your system default formats can be set in the Control Panel (>  Region -> Change date, time and number formats). When you enter Now() the system uses the format set there. Apparently you use another format when you enter the date manually, and that clashes with the format set for the cell by the code in the sub FormatCells.

Comment: Bear in mind that =Now() will recalculate whenever you make a change in that row, in fact, whenever Excel recalculates the sheet.

Comment: working sweet now. Many many thanks for your assistance, time and knowledge. I do  have another question about it calling another end time if it is day 5 (Fri) and another start and end time if it is day 6 (sat). I will start a new thread and tag yourself in it. Thankyou again :-)

Comment: I have started a new thread called " Calling a sub for different start and end times"

Answer (score 0):

The text in your event procedure should be changed in the light of changes you want to make to the code. Please replace as follows:-

```
                            MsgBox "You entered a time during which production rests." & vbCr & _
                                   "The next shift after that will start on " & _
                                    Format(Entry, "dddd,") & vbCr & _
                                    Format(Entry, "mmmm d,") & " at " & _
                                    Format(Entry, "h:mm") & "." & vbCr & _
                                    "Your entry was adjusted accordingly.", _
                                   vbInformation, "Corrected time entry"
'                            MsgBox "On " & Format(Entry, "mmm d") & " production doesn't " & _
'                                   "start until " & Format(Entry, "h:mm") & "." & vbCr & _
'                                   "Your entry was adjusted accordingly.", _
'                                   vbInformation, "Corrected time entry"
```

Meaning, look for the lines of code with apostrophes at their beginning above and replace them with the liens that don't have an apostrophe.

I suggest you post a link to this thread in the new thread you just started.